# Error importing a shapefile into DB2 spatial table using db2se import_shape

Tags: db2, spatial, db2-11.5

For a database (DB2 spatial is already enabled for it), I created a relation with the following attributes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE state.village (
    zipcode varchar(5),
    shape db2gse.st_multipolygon
);
```

And then wrote a script to load a shapefile, `villages.shp`, into the table as follows:

```sql
!db2se import_shape sample -fileName villages.shp -inputAttrColumns GEOID20 -srsName nad83_srs_1 -tableSchema state -tableName village -tableAttrColumns zipcode -createTableFlag 0 -spatialColumn shape -typeSchema db2gse -typeName st_multipolygon -messagesFile village.txt -client 1;
```

The shapefile has the following info:

```shell
...
Column Number  Column Name      Data Type       Length  Decimal
-------------  ---------------  --------------  ------  -------
            1  ZCTA5CE20        C ( Character)       5        0
            2  GEOID20          C ( Character)       5        0
            3  CLASSFP20        C ( Character)       2        0
            4  MTFCC20          C ( Character)       5        0
            5  FUNCSTAT20       C ( Character)       1        0
            6  ALAND20          N (   Numeric)      14        0
            7  AWATER20         N (   Numeric)      14        0
            8  INTPTLAT20       C ( Character)      11        0
            9  INTPTLON20       C ( Character)      12        0
```

However, each time I run this script, `db2 -tvf script.sql`, I always get this error:

```shell
GSE2108N  The method specification "G" to identify the attribute
columns to be imported from the file is not correct.
```

I have tried putting `GEOID20` in quotes, making it lowercase and using `N(GEOID20)` but none worked.

`db2level` gives the following details:

```shell
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: 
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11058" with level 
identifier "0609010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.8.0", "s2209201700", "DYN2209201700AMD64", 
and Fix Pack "0".
```

I don't quite know what's going wrong.